# difference between Flask-RESTful and Flask-RESTx

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-restx

What is the difference between Flask-RESTful and Flask-RESTx? Is it more advantageous to use Flask-RESTx instead of Flask-RESTful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the main difference between `Flask-RESTx` and `Flask-RESTful` is that `Flask-RESTx` supports auto-generated Swagger documentation. i think there are no other noticeable differences.